# How to continue logic in for-each?

Tags: kotlin

I can use `continue` in normal for loop.

```
for (i in 0..10) {
    // .. some initial code
    if (i == something) continue
    // .. some other code
}
```

But it seems I can't use it in `forEach`

```
(0 .. 10).forEach {
    // .. some initial code
    if (i == something) continue
    // .. some other code
}
```

Is there a way to use have the similar `continue` statement for `forEach`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the source code for `forEach` :

```
@kotlin.internal.HidesMembers
public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.forEach(action: (T) -> Unit): Unit {
    for (element in this) action(element)
}
```

For every element of the collection a lambda method `action` is applied. So, in order to go the next element in your `for loop` the lambda method must finish. And to finish it `return` but in scope of `@forEach` must be called:

```
(0 .. 10).forEach {
    // .. some initial code
    if (i = something) {
        return@forEach
    }
    // .. some other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `return@forEach` instead of `continue`

Comment: It's suppose to be `return@forEach`